# Automatically Number/ Count All Columns or Rows in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I just wanted a simple way to number columns or rows in a Google Sheet, and most answers I've found offer many options that are far more complicated than I needed them to be.

Example: I want to number every column in the active sheet, starting with 1 for `Column A` and counting up by 1, regardless of the content of any other cells on the sheet ***and*** if I add columns to the sheet later, I want them to automatically update with the correct column numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use `SEQUENCE`.
So putting `=SEQUENCE(99)` in A1 would number the first 99 rows, from 1 to 99.

To number columns, just rotate that array, with TRANSPOSE.
So if A1 held `=TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(26))`
that would number columns A to Z with the numbers 1 to 26.

If you want to number both columns and rows,try:

- in A1: `=SEQUENCE(999)`, and
- in B1: `=TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(25,1,2))`

I realise that this is numbering a specific number of rows, or columns, but I often find that very useful.  You could modify this to number all columns or rows by adding some count to determine the total number of rows or columns, and using that in place of the first parameter for the SEQUENCE function.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I've found to do this is by putting either of the following formulas in `A1`:

- For numbering rows: `=ArrayFormula(ROW(A:A))`
- And for columns: `=ArrayFormula(COLUMN(1:1))`

After putting the formula in `A1`, I'll usually hide the column or row the formula is in so I don't accidentally change or delete it.

If I want the counting to start at 1 on the 2nd, 3rd, or 4th row or column, then adding a `-1`,`-2`, or `-3` respectively to the end of the formula gets that done.

For example: To number columns starting with 1 in `Column C`, the formula I put in `A1` is `=ArrayFormula(COLUMN(1:1)-2)`.

This may be way more basic than most people on this site are generally looking for, but for some reason it took me an unexpectedly long time to find it/ figure it out, so I thought maybe someone else would find it useful in the future.